# What are the major differences between Views Datasource and Views data export?

Tags: importing-exporting

I'd like to create dynamic XML feed export using View based on my content type nodes.

There are two huge modules: [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) (17k usage) and [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) (67k usage) which sounds pretty similar.

On Views data export homepage we can read that:

> *Views Datasource* allows exporting to XML/JSON among many others, but is geared towards small exports.

Does it mean *Views Datasource* should be used only for small exports?

In other words, what are the main differences between these two modules? And what are the preferred ways (use cases) of using one over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views Datasource can be thought as providing a view format that takes over the whole page; each submodule you enabled (JSON/RDF/XHTML/XML) provides a format that it outputs the view as a specified document type without your site theme.

Views Data Export can be thought of providing an attached exportable format of some complementary view format (e.g. a Page view formatted as a table that as an exportable CSV file); when enabled, it provides a new view display that you can make available at a specified path and attached to existing view as a button which can be configured to be a downloadable attachment.

There is some overlap (e.g. both could be used to produce an XML-producing custom path), but only Views Datasource provides a JSON (unless you use some other [contrib module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export_json)), while Views Data Export has other options (e.g. batching support) that make it better suited for large data exports.